# How can I use FastApi through IIS using httpPlatformHandler

Tags: python-3.x, iis, fastapi, httpplatformhandler

I am having some issues trying to get a Python 3.7 FastAPI working through IIS.

Following instructions to configure [Microsoft httpPlatformHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler), I have managed to get a basic response working through adding the following configuration:

```
<httpPlatform requestTimeout="00:05:00" startupTimeLimit="120" startupRetryCount="3" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="c:\logs\fast" processPath="c:\python3\python.exe" arguments="-m uvicorn webapis.api.fast:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
    </environmentVariables>
</httpPlatform>
```

This works, in the sense that Uvicorn is correctly started and I do get back a response object generated by FastAPI:

```
{
    "detail": "Not Found"
}
```

The issue is that the actual query is always returning a `404` response and the logs show that information I don't want to pass is being sent to the API:

```
INFO:     [::1]:56395:0 - "GET /webapis/api/fast.py/hello/bob HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Essentially, I need to strip `/webapis/api/fast.py` from what is being passed into my FastAPI. I think the [Reverse proxy with URL rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing) is what I need here, but I can't get this to work. I have tried adding the following to my `web.config` with a separately started Uvicorn server on port 8000

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to FastApi" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^webapis/api/fast.py/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8000/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This results in an IIS generated `404` error and I can see from the logs in the Uvicorn process running on port 8000 that no request is ever forwarded to it. Thinking the `httpPlatformHandler` config may be interfering, I tried changing the `fast.py` portion of the match URL to simply `fast`, but the same result occurs

I'm not very familiar with IIS and would really appreciate any guidance anyone could provide on how to properly configure `httpPlatformHandler` / `URL Rewrite` to achieve my goal

Thank you

Comment: Please roll back your attempt on IIS rewrite rules, and instead mount the sub application as documented, https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This doesn't work. If we read about the use of `root_path` behind a proxy, we can see why

Comment: It looks like you are trying to set up a reverse proxy with URL rewrite in IIS to forward requests to your FastAPI application running on a separate Uvicorn server.  Where is your web.config file located? Have you installed the Application Request Routing module and enabled proxy functionality?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have left the company now and can't answer your question about the ARR module. I'll pass it on to the team to check this. The `web.config` file is located in the root site directory and it does have other URL rewrite rules in place

Comment: If you and your team verify that the cause is not the ARR module, I recommend using failed request tracking, which will provide key errors and warnings to help you locate the problem.
This link provides ways to enable failed request tracing to capture detailed errors: https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.